# pytest - detecting whether code executes in a test run

Tags: pytest

I would like to test a pyqt5 gui (python 3.9).
The gui has a number of buttons which trigger hardware actions.
 For testing the gui only I do not want to trigger these hardware actions, only verify that the button is connected with the correct function.
How can I suppress the call to the hardware function when the button has been activated by pytest and not in a productive situation by a user?

Comment: Mock the function the button is connected to, then call [`assert_called`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) to verify the function is called on button action.

Comment: Thanks, started to read about mocking, not an expert yet ...